# Turn 3D multipolygon with missing faces into cube

Tags: postgis

I have data of buildings that are missing walls, like this

```sql
MULTIPOLYGON(((5 5 0, 5 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 5 0, 5 5 0),(5 5 5, 5 0 5, 0 0 5, 0 5 5, 5 5 5)))
```

This would be the floor and roof, stretching from 0 to 5 at a height of 0 and 5 respectively. What I need is to fill the walls in, resulting in the entire object being returned either as TIN or POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z.

I have tried ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) like this

```sql
Select ST_asewkt(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromEWKT('MULTIPOLYGON(((5 5 0, 5 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 5 0, 5 5 0),
                                                                         (5 5 5, 5 0 5, 0 0 5, 0 5 5, 5 5 5)))'))))
```

returns only the floor as polygon

```sql
POLYGON((0 0 0,0 5 0,5 5 0,5 0 0,0 0 0))
```

and if I were to use 3DUnion like this

```sql
Select ST_asewkt(ST_3DUnion(ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((5 5 0, 5 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 5 0, 5 5 0))'), 
                            ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((5 5 5, 5 0 5, 0 0 5, 0 5 5, 5 5 5))')
))
```

it only returns TINs of the floor and the roof

```sql
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(TIN(((5 5 0,5 0 0,0 0 0,5 5 0)),((0 5 0,5 5 0,0 0 0,0 5 0))),TIN(((5 5 5,5 0 5,0 0 5,5 5 5)),((0 5 5,5 5 5,0 0 5,0 5 5))))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?